# How to T-SQL SELECT into C# variables

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 and C# ASP.NET 4

I have this simplified table named myTable including the columns:
Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[myTable](
    [Col1] [int] NULL,
    [Col2] [int] NULL,
    [Col3] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Col4] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[myTable] ([Col1], [Col2], [Col3], [Col4]) VALUES (0, 0, N'@', 0)
INSERT [dbo].[myTable] ([Col1], [Col2], [Col3], [Col4]) VALUES (1, 2, N'c', 4)
INSERT [dbo].[myTable] ([Col1], [Col2], [Col3], [Col4]) VALUES (11, 22, N'cc', 44)
```

(The original table is much wider)

How to `SELECT` two (or 20 or 200) column into C# variables or array/list of variables, or anything else which will be effective as or better than sometihng like that:

```
object obj = new object();
string sql = "SELECT Col2, Col3 FROM myTable WHERE Col1=0";
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(mySqlCalss.DatabaseConnectionString() ))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                cmd.Connection.Open();
                obj = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

in a way I could use something like:

```
int myVar1 = (int)ojb[0];
string myVar2 = (string)obj[1];
```

then:

```
lblMyASPlable1.Text = myVar1.ToString();
lblMyASPlable2.Text = myVar2;
```

?

Comment: Have you looked for ADO.NET tutorials? This is a basic task covered extensively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `SQLDataAdapter`

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
string sql = "SELECT Col2, Col3 FROM myTable WHERE Col1=0";
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(mySqlCalss.DatabaseConnectionString() ))
{
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
   cmd.Connection.Open();
   SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
   adapter.Fill(table);                
}
```

And

```
int myVar1;
string myVar2;
if(table.Rows.Count>0)
{
  myVar1 = (int)table.Rows[0]["Col2"];
  myVar2 = (string)table.Rows[0]["Col3"];
}
```

Comment: @Asif- I found no ExecuteQuery. I get this error message: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'

Comment: don't define obj, rather use var = cmd.ExecuteQuery();

Comment: @Asif- Still, I get the following error message, what am I missing: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand' does not contain a definition for 'ExecuteQuery' and no extension method 'ExecuteQuery' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: myVar1 = (int)table.Rows[0][0]

Comment: Thanks, it works! Do you know about a way to set names to use it like myVar1=(int)table.Rows[0]['Col2'] ... Then it will be like meaningful variables.

Comment: Yes you can also use it like myVar1 = (int)table.Rows[0]["col2"]

Answer (score 3):

You're using "ExecuteNonQuery", this does what it says on the tin and doesn't execute like a query i.e. a select. Try ExecuteReader.

```
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", reader[0]));
}
```

Comment: Can't writeLine, it's asp.net webpage, and I need the variables, the presentation is an extra.

Comment: Then ignore the WriteLine. It's the reader[0] part that extracts the value

Answer (score 1):

Use reading into `DataReader` [see Datareader in action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into a MicroORM like [dapper](https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/)